# How to split long numbers by commas to readable number using php?

Tags: php, string, text, numbers

Am fetching a price from my database. It is being displayed using.
It display the prices as follows: `5000000`

How can i split it to display something like `5,000,000`

Comment: use `money_format` http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php

Comment: @jitendrapurohit `money_format()` add money sign at first of string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have you tried [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)?

number_format does exactly what you want:

```
<?php
$number = 5000000;
echo number_format($number); //output: 5,000,000
```

Answer (score 2):

**use `money_format(string,number)`**

> (Money format not fit for windows)

[money_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php)

**also use  `number_format()**

> number_format — Format a number with grouped thousands

`<?php echo number_format("5000000")."<br>"; ?>`

[number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Comment: it should be [noted](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php#refsect1-function.money-format-notes): money_format is not available on windows-systems - and the locale has to be set correctly before using it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the php built in function number_format for this

```
echo number_format($price);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$number = 1234.56;

// let's print the international format for the en_US locale
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
echo money_format('%i', $number) . "\n";
// USD 1,234.56

// Italian national format with 2 decimals`
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'it_IT');
echo money_format('%.2n', $number) . "\n";
// Eu 1.234,56

// Using a negative number
$number = -1234.5672;

// US national format, using () for negative numbers
// and 10 digits for left precision
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
echo money_format('%(#10n', $number) . "\n";
// ($        1,234.57)

// Similar format as above, adding the use of 2 digits of right
// precision and '*' as a fill character
echo money_format('%=*(#10.2n', $number) . "\n";
// ($********1,234.57)

// Let's justify to the left, with 14 positions of width, 8 digits of
// left precision, 2 of right precision, withouth grouping character
// and using the international format for the de_DE locale.
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'de_DE');
echo money_format('%=*^-14#8.2i', 1234.56) . "\n";
// Eu 1234,56****

// Let's add some blurb before and after the conversion specification
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_GB');
$fmt = 'The final value is %i (after a 10%% discount)';
echo money_format($fmt, 1234.56) . "\n";
// The final value is  GBP 1,234.56 (after a 10% discount)

?>
```

Comment: its better to add reference url also.

Comment: simply copying code from another page without any explanation by yourself or any reference to the source is *not* very nice. you could've just said you got it from [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php)